# Does Lua optimize concatenating with an empty string?

Tags: string, performance, lua, string-concatenation

I have two strings. One of them is often (but not always) empty. The other is huge:

```
a = ""
b = "... huge string ..."
```

I need to concatenate the two strings. So I do the following:

```
return a .. b
```

But, if `a` is empty, this would, temporarily, unnecessarily create a copy of the huge string.

So I thought to write it as follows:

```
return (a == "" and b) or (a .. b)
```

This would solve the problem. But, I was wondering: does Lua optimize a concatenation that involves an empty string? That is, if we write `a .. b`, does Lua check to see if either of the strings is empty and return the other one immediately? If so, I could simply write `a ..b` instead of the more elaborate code.

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138974/does-lua-optimize-the-operator

Comment: @filmor: It was I myself who asked that other question, which is not related to this one: that other question talks about folding `((a .. b) .. c) .. d` into `..(a,b,c,d)`. *This* question deals with something entirely else.

Comment: @Leri: I don't see how inspecting the bytecodes could help me answer the question: the string is either empty or not *at run time*, not at compile time. The code I wrote above, `a = ""`, is just to explain matters. It'd be `a = ...some expression... ` in real life.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. But in this question you have already been pointed to the source code of the relevant function.

Comment: @filmor: Yeah, I knew how I could figure out the answer to my own question, but I wanted to hear the perspective of experienced/wise users here. I almost always learn new things by reading answers to questions I already, or think I already, know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does.

In the Lua 5.2 source code [`luaV_concat`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html#luaV_concat):

```c
if (!(ttisstring(top-2) || ttisnumber(top-2)) || !tostring(L, top-1)) {
  if (!call_binTM(L, top-2, top-1, top-2, TM_CONCAT))
    luaG_concaterror(L, top-2, top-1);
}
else if (tsvalue(top-1)->len == 0)  /* second operand is empty? */
  (void)tostring(L, top - 2);  /* result is first operand */
else if (ttisstring(top-2) && tsvalue(top-2)->len == 0) {
  setobjs2s(L, top - 2, top - 1);  /* result is second op. */
}
else {
  /* at least two non-empty string values; get as many as possible */
```

The two `else if` parts are exactly doing the job of optimizing string concatenation when one of the operand is an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I see that Lua 5.1 (which I target) [doesn't do this optimization](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lvm.c.html#luaV_concat). LuaJIT seems to be [even worse](https://github.com/LuaDist/luajit/blob/master/src/lj_api.c#L704). So I'll have to do this optimization myself. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @NiccoloM. That's interesting, didn't know the difference. There seems to be a check for zero length in both Lua 5.1 and LuaJIT source at first glance, but I didn't get into detail, I'll remember to update the answer when I'm sure what they do.

Comment: @NiccoloM. Keep in mind that a) that's not the official LuaJIT repo and b) LuaJIT's concat operator probably doesn't use `lua_concat` internally, but rather its own internal API.

Comment: @Yu Hao: Oh, I now see the zero check in 5.1, but I don't know what exactly it does. I'd greatly appreciate it if you update your answer when you find the time to investigate this.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: I agree that my comment was naive; I did wrote "seems to"; I wish somebody who knows luaJIT better could chime in.